# Rotating div with mouse

Tags: javascript, css

I am building time picker in js where you can set hours on "Real" clocks.
I'm rotating div with this script:

```
if (e.target.id == "rotationSliderContainer") {
    g = e.offsetX;
    h = e.offsetY;
}
var atan = Math.atan2(g - radius, h - radius);
deg = -atan / (Math.PI / 180) + 180;
```

Although it works it has a little bug, whenever you try to move div between 2/3 and 9/10 its "stops" or freezes, it even returns degrees as `NaN` when I am rotating div while mouse is still on the div.

I can't find any solution to this little problem.I tried to use `asin()` instead of `atan2` but it still didn't work.

Did I overlook something? demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afo7ky03/6/

Comment: It's working fine for me.  It might be a browser compatibility issue as opposed to a javascript problem.  I'll look a little more into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem

```
<div id="rotationSliderDegrees">0&deg;</div>
```

Look in your web developer tools and you'll see that the div stops because your mouse is passing through this div.

Comment: wow , i spend quite a while on this problem .. it was so simple! thanks!